# Объединение csv файлов в sed

Tags: linux, python-3.x, csv, sed

После выполнения команды

```
 sed 1d *.csv > merg.csv
```

В файле появляются подобные квадраты, в исходных файлах подобного нет, это очень мешает итерироваться по ним с помощью модуля csv.reader Python3

Даже если я прописываю подобную обработку исключения, или включаю её прямо в цикл for с вызовом continue при исключении. То итерация останавливается без ошибок на стыке первого и второго файла.

Буду признателен, если кто-то мне поможет.

```
try:
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
except _csv.Error: pass
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: «в исходных файлах подобного нет» — не верю, примеры файлов в студию (хотя бы шапки и хвосты).

Comment: лучше приложите к тексту вопроса (нажав [edit]) начала и концы вывода `hexdump -C` для пары файлов, при обработке которых возникают эти артефакты. начало: `$ hexdump -C файл | head`, конец: `$ hexdump -C файл | tail`

Comment: Да, действительно - моя ошибка, квадраты эти в исходных файлах всё-таки есть, а есть ли возможность с помощью sed при объединении файлов отрезать последние n строк каждого файла?

Comment: последняя строка адресуется как `$` (удаление её: `sed '$d' файл`). адресация других строк относительно последней [несколько громоздка у программы sed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13380607/4827341).

Answer (score 0):

`sed`'ом проще оставить нужное по маске, например по mac'ам вначале строки:

```
sed -rne '/^([0-9A-F]{2}:){5}[0-9A-F]{2}/p' *.csv > merge.csv
```

А обрезать строки вначале/конце проще `head`'ом/`tail`'ом (убирает первую строку и последние 3):

```
for f in *.csv; do head -n -3 $f | tail -n +2; done > merge.csv
```