# передача содержимого файла двум командам одновременно не всегда работает

Tags: bash

почему конструкции 1 и 2 работают как и ожидается, а конструкция 3 выводит только количество строк?

1. вывод первой и последней строк из файла:

   ```
   $ (head -n 1; tail -n 1) < файл
   ```
2. вывод первой строки и количества строк файла:

   ```
   $ (head -n 1; wc -l) < файл
   ```

   (**обновление1:** на самом деле оказалось, что работает не совсем так: `wc` выводит число, на единицу меньшее длины файла — эту строку «съедает» `head`).
3. вывод количества строк файла и затем первой строки (не работает — выводится только количество строк):

   ```
   $ (wc -l; head -n 1) < файл
   ```

**обновление2:** по поводу «особой реализации» программы *head* из состава *gnu/coreutils* можно возразить, что «busybox»-овая, например, реализация, ведёт себя идентично. такая команда выводит то же самое, что и в пункте 1:

```
$ (busybox head -n 1; tail -n 1) < файл
```

и вообще, «списать всё» на реализацию *head* вряд ли можно. ведь поведение конструкций:

```
$ cat файл | (head -n 1; tail -n 1)
$ (head -n 1; tail -n 1) < <(cat файл)
```

не совпадает с приведённым в первом примере: выводится только первая строка файла.

---

версии программ (хотя это, скорее всего, вряд ли существенно):

```
$ head --version
head (GNU coreutils) 8.26
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by David MacKenzie and Jim Meyering.
$ wc --version
wc (GNU coreutils) 8.26
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Paul Rubin and David MacKenzie.
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

p.s. и интересно бы узнать, где вообще подобная конструкция (`(команда1; команда2) < файл`) задокументирована.

Comment: для частного примера (не имеет отношения к сути вопроса), [можно `sed -e 1b -e '$!d'` использовать](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139089/1321)

Comment: @jfs, одна строка — это просто частный случай. вообще всё началось с попытки запихнуть в одну команду то, что я написал вот в этом комментарии: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/819087/#comment1302698_819087

Comment: related: [What is the difference between "cat file | ./binary" and "./binary < file"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/337739/1321)

Comment: related: [Is this tail behavior in Grouping Commands specified by POSIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/239558/1321)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

правильный вопрос, на который следует отвечать, это:

почему вообще работает конструкция `(head -n 1; head -n 1) < файл` (ниже упоминается как «исходная команда»), выдавая при этом две первые строки файла?

ответив на него правильно, можно будет ответить и на остальные прозвучавшие вопросы.

ответ получен после просмотра трассировки работы программы *head*. тестовый файл:

```
$ cat file
first line
second line
last line
```

запускаем под *gnu/linux* (здесь исходная команда выдаёт две строки):

```
$ (strace head -n 1; head -n 1) < file
read(0, "first line\nsecond line\nlast line"..., 8192) = 33
lseek(0, -22, SEEK_CUR)                 = 11
write(1, "first line\n", 11)            = 11
```

запускаем под *solaris* (здесь исходная команда выдаёт тоже две строки):

```
$ (truss head -n 1; head -n 1) < file
read(0, " f i r s t   l i n e\n s".., 4096)     = 33
write(1, " f i r s t   l i n e\n", 11)          = 11
llseek(0, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEA, SEEK_CUR)         = 11
```

запускаем под *freebsd* (здесь исходная команда выдаёт только первую строку):

```
$ (truss head -n 1 ; head -n 1) < file
read(0,"first line\nsecond line\nlast li"...,32768) = 33 (0x21)
write(1,"first line\n",11)           = 11 (0xb)
```

оставлены только существенные строки вывода. из них видно, что программа *head* во всех трёх реализациях считывает все 33 байта из *stdin* (связанного оболочкой с реальным файлом), а затем записывает первые 11 в *stdout*.

но в случае *gnu/linux* и *solaris* после чтения производится «перемотка» указателя (*lseek/llseek*) на позицию 11 во входном файле (к началу второй строки), а во *freebsd* этого не происходит.

---

отсюда становится понятным, почему идентичная вроде бы конструкция:

```
$ cat файл | (head -n 1; head -n 1)
```

работает одинаково во всех трёх тестируемых системах (выдавая только первую строку файла): ведь сделать «перемотку» можно только в реальном файле, а когда это не файл, а поток, передаваемый через «трубу» (*pipe*, `|`), то переставить указатель невозможно.

Comment: А теперь самое интересное: почему `(head -n 1; tail -n 1) <file` во FreeBSD работает? И почему перемотка файлового дескриптора в другом процессе влияет на родителя? (в linux'е финт ушами через clone(), а в остальных?)

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ну это уж вам «на закуску».

Comment: да, второй вопрос про файловые дескрипторы — глупый был — так и должно работать... и `clone ()` я зря тут приплёл...  а вот про `(head -n 1; tail -n 1)` — что-то непонятно, но прокопать у меня не получается — `truss` какую-то ерунду с флагом `-f` выводит (в частности не видно `exec`'а), а strace не взлетает...

Comment: lol, всё просто... tail делает `lseek(0,0x0,SEEK_CUR)` перед чтением...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, так указатель, насколько я понимаю, **уже** находится в конце файла. и потому второй `head` в связке `head+head` ничего не выводит (freebsd). если дальше `tail` не «отматывает» на отрицательную величину, то как же он выводит последнюю строку (в связке `head+tail` под freebsd)?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, видимо в bsd tail отматывает (читает сзади наперед (я, например, так бы его и писал)). Интересно, что в GNU он, похоже, рассматривает данные от SEEK_CUR (попробуйте, например, `(head -n 1; tail -n 6) <t.txt`) до конца файла (и в этом случае тоже может читать сзади наперед)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, да, прошу прощения, хотел обмануть... `tail` просто [`mmap`'ит](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/b75e4698e930e0e5f87f806092cf5345049b0d08/usr.bin/tail/forward.c#L211) файл...  а truss ввёл меня в заблуждение: после печати строк он показал ещё какой-то `lseek ():  и чтение файла:https://paste.pound-python.org/show/gRKZpGlFJmeClqIajuE4/

Comment: @Fat-Zer: ваша ссылка явно показывает: `lseek(0,0x0,SEEK_SET) 
read(0,"head_line\nbody\ntail_line\n",16384)` (то есть отмотать до начала файла, прочитать всё).

Comment: @jfs, меня это как раз запутало сначала, но вывод ответа происходит **до** этого, на 38-й строке. соответственно вычисляется он с помощью mmap'а на 37-й.

Answer (score 3):

В самой конструкции `(команда1; команда2) < файл` нет ничего примечательного: запускается *subshell*, которому на вход задаётся *файл*. В *subshell*'е выполняется сначала *команда1* потом *команда2*. Обе они читают из одного stdin'а по очереди.

В упрощённом варианте об этом можно думать следующим образом:

1. `head` читает первую строчку, после этого останавливается и выводит её, остальное читает `tail`. Но AFAIK данное поведение ни как не стандартизовано.
2. Аналогично, `head` читает первую строчку, а все остальные достаются `wc`. `wc` выводит выводит количество строк на единицу меньше.
3. `wc` читает всё, а `head'`у ничего не достаются.

Всё это довольно грязные вещи и то что первая команда работает завязано исключительно на реализации GNU `head`. полагаться на это нельзя.

Корректно перенаправить вывод двум разным процессам на `bash` можно например так:

```
tee >(head -n1) >(tail -n1) >/dev/null
```

Но порядок вывода `head` и `tail` на терминал не определён.

В Базовой POSIX-совместимой оболочке AFAIK это можно сделать только с помощью именованных каналов.

**Update**

### Результаты тестирования различных оболочках:

Подопытный файл:

```
$ cat /tmp/file
head_line
body
tail_line
```

Проверенные оболочки:
* GNU/Linux: bash, dash, bussybox sh
* FreeBSD 8.0: csh, bash

Тестовые команды:

1. `<shell> -c 'cat /tmp/file | (head -n 1; tail -n 1)'`
   `<shell> -c 'cat /tmp/file | (head -n 1; head -n 1)'`
   На всех оболочках даёт одинаковый результат:

   ```
   head_line
   ```
2. `$ <shell> -c '(head -n 1; tail -n 1) </tmp/file'`

   ```
   head_line
   tail_line
   ```
3. `$ <shell> -c '(head -n 1; head -n 1) </tmp/file'`

   - GNU/Linux (все оболочки):

     ```
     head_line
     body
     ```
   - FreeBSD 8 (все оболочки):

     ```
     head_line
     ```

Comment: *нет ничего примечательного* — немного примечательного всё-таки есть. иначе бы поведение и `$ (head -n 1; tail -n 1) < файл`, и `$ cat файл | (head -n 1; tail -n 1)`, и `$ (head -n 1: tail -n 1) < <(cat файл)` не отличалось (с моей точки зрения). а оно отличается.

Comment: а поведение `$ (busybox head -n 1; tail -n 1) < файл` ничем не отличается ни от `$ (head -n 1; tail -n 1) < файл`, ни от `$ (busybox head -n 1; busybox tail -n 1) < файл`. версия дебиановского пакета busybox — `1:1.22.0-19+b3`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, добавь первый коментрий к вопросу... объяснение в принципе тоже — особенности реализации, но нужно небольшое исследование и я подозреваю, что детальные причины в различии несколько другие и куда более интересные... ЗЫ: что-то у меня сегодня коментарии через раз отправляются...

Comment: @alexanderbarakin  эффекты от `cat file |` (pipe) и `< file` (перенаправление) могут отличаться, но во многих случаях взаимозаменяемы.

Comment: busybox и gnu head, tail в данном случае себя одинаково ведут. Вариант с перенаправлением файла работает и на busybox: `echo -e '1\n2\n3' >/tmp/a && docker run -v /tmp:/tmp --rm -i alpine:3.7 sh -c '(head -n 1; tail -n 1) </tmp/a'` и наоборот вариант с pipe не работает и на gnu head: `echo -e '1\n2\n3' | docker run --rm -i ubuntu:18.04 sh -c 'head -n 1; tail -n 1'`. Кратко: `<file` работает,  а `cat file |` не работает с обоими версиями head,tail.

Comment: @jfs, да, спасибо, я уже тоже натестировался (на пару с коллегой), и пишу свой вариант ответа.

Answer (score 3):

> почему конструкции 1 и 2 работают как и ожидается, а конструкция 3 выводит только количество строк?

`<файл` в shell ([POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07), [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections)) перенаправляет файл в стандартный ввод (команда, читающая из stdin (fd 0), получит содержимое файла). `wc -l` в п. 3 читает весь ввод, поэтому на долю `head` ничего не остаётся.

То что `head -n 1` не потребляет весь ввод (что позволяет работать командам в п. 1 и п. 2) не гарантируется документацией для утилиты `head`(как [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html) так и [Gnu](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/head-invocation.html)). Разумно ожидать, что лишняя работа не будет выполняться, особенно если это не усложняет реализацию. К примеру, [FreeBSD `head.c`](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/b75e4698e930e0e5f87f806092cf5345049b0d08/usr.bin/head/head.c#L140):

```
while (cnt && (cp = fgetln(fp, &readlen)) != NULL) {
```

[`fgetln()`](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/34f7d1c6914cbc7b135fed887b991d5fd9320f40/lib/libc/stdio/fgetln.c#L103) использует stdio буфер, поэтому может прочесть из стандартного ввода больше необходимого. Это объясняет почему на FreeBSD `(head -n 1; head -n 1) <файл` [не работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/819327/23044). `tail` может [игнорировать текущую позицию в файле](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/b75e4698e930e0e5f87f806092cf5345049b0d08/usr.bin/tail/forward.c#L96) как [@Fat-Zer  выяснил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/819225/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82#comment1303397_819327). Поэтому `(head -n 1; tail -n 1) <file` может работать и на FreeBSD.

[GNU head.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/head.c#n797) также может прочитать больше необходимого (`BUFSIZ`), но при чтении из seek-able файла пытается откатиться на позицию, которая бы получилась, если бы команда по одному байту читала (то есть при чтении одной строки, попытка выставить позицию в [конце строки](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/head.c#n818)). Это поведение не гарантировано [документацией самой утилиты head](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/head-invocation.html).

Так как pipe не являются seek-able это объясняет, почему вариант с `cat file|` не работает.

**Согласно [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html) стандартные утилиты (такие как head, sed, tail) обязаны позицию файла выставлять для seekable ввода** ([Is this tail behavior in Grouping Commands specified by POSIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/239558/1321)):

> When a standard utility reads a seekable input file and terminates
>   without an error before it reaches end-of-file, the utility shall
>   ensure that the file offset in the open file description is properly
>   positioned just past the last byte processed by the utility. For files
>   that are not seekable, the state of the file offset in the open file
>   description for that file is unspecified. A conforming application
>   shall not assume that the following three commands are equivalent:
>
> ```
>    tail -n +2 file
>    (sed -n 1q; cat) < file
>    cat file | (sed -n 1q; cat)
> ```

то есть на POSIX поведение для `(head -n 1; tail -n 1) <file` гарантировано.

> где вообще подобная конструкция ((команда1; команда2) <файл) задокументирована

[`( compound-list )`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04) команды выполняются в subshell (чаще встречается, чем может показаться, к примеру каждая команда в pipeline может в subshell (в отдельном процессе) выполняться). Если отдельный процесс не нужен, то можно  `{ compound-list ; }`  конструкцию использовать (перенаправление по прежнему работает).

Если не ясно как перенаправление работает и как дополнение к официальной документации — [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07), [bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections) можно [на вводное руководство с диаграммами посмотреть](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial).

Comment: как оказалось, пункт 1 под freebsd [таки работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/819225/819379#comment1303154_819327). я сам в шоке. реально работает как минимум у меня и у @Fat-Zer

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Согласно POSIX, стандартные утилиты обязаны позицию подправлять для seekable ввода. Я на freebsd не тестировал, поэтому ссылку на ваш ответ привёл (что не работает). Согласно исходному коду для head, fgetln (ссылки в ответе выше) и не должен этот случай работать (слова seek только в комментарии), если ввод fully buffered. При перенаправлении из файла, pipe на моей (ubuntu) машине ввод  fully buffered (8K за раз читается).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: для ясности: вы говорите, что фраза *"здесь исходная команда выдаёт только первую строку"* из [вашего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/819327/23044) не соответствует действительности?

Comment: @jfs, у него в ответе **другая** команда, не та, что в вопросе. Первая **из вопроса** почему-то работает...

Comment: @Fat-Zer разница не существенна. Если POSIX поведение, то для данного ввода две строки должно быть, а не одна. Поэтому вопрос остаётся: соответсвует ли действительности фраза из ответа.

Comment: @jfs, сам же на исходники сослался, понятно, что BSD отступает от поведения продиктованного POSIX. По поводу фразы — смотря что понимать под «исходная команда»: если `(head -n 1; tail -n 1)`, то *не соответствует*, если `(head -n 1; tail -n 1)`, то *соответствует*. ЗЫ: причину нашёл: см. комментарий ответу @alexanderbarakin...

Comment: в вопросе упоминается `head+tail`, в ответе `head+head`. разница между ними достаточна для того, чтобы первый вариант выдавал под freebsd одну строку, а второй — две (подразумевается, что присутствуют опции `-n 1`)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: должно быть наоборот: head+head -> одна строка, а  head+tail -- две.

Comment: @jfs, да, опечатался.

Answer (score 1):

> почему конструкции 1 и 2 работают как и ожидается, а конструкция 3
>   выводит только количество строк?

Потому, что shell делает *один* `open()`, а потом 2 раза `dup2()`. В результате `stdin` в командах делит общий указатель чтения-записи, связанный с файловым дескриптором, *который вернул* `open`.

Несколько неожиданно действительно аккуратное поведение `head`, (а `tail` меня реально в этом плане поразил (см. фактуру в ответах и комментариях @alexanderbarakin, @Fat-Zer и @jfs)), которые сдвигают указатель на *логически верную* позицию, соответствующую байтам, которые они реально бы обработали при последовательном чтении файла.